# How can I do a interval condition correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql

I did a query to show information according an interval.

**HERE IS THE TABLE**

```
|id|  |date_payment|
  1    '2014-11-18' 
  2    '2014-12-18'     
  3    '2015-01-27' 
  5    '2015-03-20' 
  6    '2015-04-18' 
  7    '2015-05-27' 
  8    '2015-06-20' 
  9    '2015-07-18' 
 10    '2015-08-27'
 11    '2015-09-20'
```

I'm trying to show information using **Year** and **Month**

For example using the year = 2014 and month = 11 as dinamic values according an interval of 4 months and should have this result:

```
|id|  |date_payment|
  1    '2014-11-18' 
  2    '2014-12-18'     
  3    '2015-01-27'
```

Here is my query:

```
 SET @var_year = '2014';
 SET @var_month = '11';

 SELECT * FROM payments
 WHERE date_payment = DATE_ADD('2014-11', INTERVAL 4 MONTH)
```

My query is not working and showing results.

[Here is the live example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/013b6/23)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DATE_ADD INTERVAL 4 MONTH` is just adding 4 month to your date `('2014-11-01')`

This query will return what you are expecting

```
SET @var_year = '2014';
SET @var_month = '11';

SET @from = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@var_year, '/', @var_month, '/01'), '%Y/%m/%d');
SET @to = DATE_ADD(@from, INTERVAL 4 MONTH);

SELECT * FROM payments
WHERE date_payment BETWEEN @from AND @to;
```

Here you have the live example

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/013b6/42

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with dynamic date.  Let me see if I can understand with an example, for example you have year and month, let suppose 2014/11 the range you want is 2014/07/01 to 2015/03/31?

Comment: Ok.  The period will be from 2014/11/01 to 2015/01/31.  Is that correct?

Comment: I edited my answer.  I added `Interval` as a variable to do the math to get the `to` value.

Comment: Sorry, it was a test and I forgot to remove it.  Also, it can be simpified :)

Comment: That was the test with the second.  I am just adding @ Interval to the from parameter.  My initial idea was add @ Interval + 1 and decrease 1 second to get the last second of the month because `BETWEEN` is inclusive in both ends.  Now, it is taking the first day of the month and just adding the interval.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @var_year = '2014';
SET @var_month = '11';

SELECT * FROM payments
WHERE date_payment = CONCAT(@var_year, '-', @var_month, '-01') + INTERVAL 4 MONTH;
```

Because:

```
SET @var_year = '2014';
SET @var_month = '11';

SELECT CONCAT(@var_year, '-', @var_month, '-01') + INTERVAL 4 MONTH AS date;
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2015-03-01 |
+------------+
```